# Working around A2DP and HFP limitations of Android Pre-HoneyComb

Tags: android, bluetooth, a2dp

I'm researching an interesting project involving mixing streaming audio over Bluetooth for smart phones, starting with android since it's what I have the most experience with.  I've worked with Bluetooth on android once or twice and in my experiences have learned that the pre-honeycomb API doesn't allow for applications to connect to A2DP or HFP audio sinks.  I've already tried this on Ginger Bread on an HTC EVO, using the necessary UUID to no avail.

According to the official documentation, as of [API LEVEL 11](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html#level11), this is now possible, but I'm pretty sure the only devices that will offer this API level will be Ice Cream Sandwich devices later on, since support started only in Honey Comb.  I'm a total amateur so it isn't likely that I will get my mitts on a development grade Ice Cream Sandwich device any time soon.  Adapting any code for later revisions wouldn't be a problem right since I'm just looking to prove concept right now.

Ideally, I would like use the input/output streams of a paired A2DP device to read and write PCM data directly.  However if I want to do this now, I will more than likely have to use a workaround.

My idea is to use android's [AudioRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) and [AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html) classes which, according to my understanding read audio input from the mic and push audio output to the speaker.  Now in both cases, when an A2DP device is not connected, these structures will use the device's mic and speaker respectively.  However when an A2DP or HFP device is connected, I'm unaware of whether or not the system would now set these structures respective input and output to the mic and speaker of the headset.  If so, then I could effectively work this into my code and adapt it later to take advantage of the direct support in Ice Cream Sandwich.

Does anyone with relatively strong experience in this area think that this approach would work?  I'd rather know if anyone has been successful, before I sit down and write some code that could potentially be a waste of time.

Comment: I don't think that the Honeycomb nor Ice Cream Sandwich APIs allow you to programmatically connect to A2DP or HFP audio sinks either.. do they?  Looking at the documentation, I don't see anything and looking at the code, it seems as those methods are hidden.  And, since the constructor is package scope, you can't get a reference unless you use a service listener and therefore can't call them even when using the hidden APIs.  Please let me know if I am wrong on this as I am trying to do something similar.

Comment: sorry for my tardiness. You're correct they do not actually give you access to the audio sink either.  HC and ICS merely offer a proxy object to allow to notify you when it is or not.  It seems the only way to accomplish what I was interested in would be only outputting audio while A2DP is connected.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Android doesn't have an official API to connect a2dp devices.
But you can use reflection to access hidden classes. I used this way in my project and it works from android 2.3 to android 4.1.
First, you need to get the IBluetoothA2dp.aidl file and put it in you project folder **src/com.android**
Next, use method below to get IBluetoothA2dp interface:

```
private static IBluetoothA2dp getIBluetoothA2dp() {
    IBluetoothA2dp ibta = null;

    try {
        final Class serviceManager = Class.forName("android.os.ServiceManager");
        final Method getService = serviceManager.getDeclaredMethod("getService", String.class);
        final IBinder iBinder = (IBinder) getService.invoke(null, "bluetooth_a2dp");
        final Class iBluetoothA2dp = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.IBluetoothA2dp");
        final Class[] declaredClasses = iBluetoothA2dp.getDeclaredClasses();
        final Class c = declaredClasses[0];
        final Method asInterface = c.getDeclaredMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class);

        asInterface.setAccessible(true);
        ibta = (IBluetoothA2dp) asInterface.invoke(null, iBinder);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return ibta;
}
```

Then if you SDK < 11 just call **a2dp.connectSink(btDevice)** or **a2dp.connect(btDevice)** if your SDK between 11 and 16.
**It doesn't work on Android 4.2** because of completely changed bluetooth stack.